# Issue with `` within .replace() tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

How can I edit my current code to work with ``` `` ``` within replace.
As of current because it's inside a loop `.each` it will find the correct word but then add `<span></span>` around that word like 6 times. I want it to only add it *once*, so I read you can use `/g` for that, however using ``` `` ``` I think is causing my issue, however I don't know how to incorporate both?

Here is my JS:

```
$("#pstad-descrptn-mirror div").each(function () {
   let get_pstad_desc_div = $(this).text();
   let get_pstad_desc_STORE = get_pstad_desc_div
       .split(", and comes with")[0]
       .split("located in ")[1];                

   $(this).html(function () {
      return $(this)
        .html()
        .replace(
           `/(${get_pstad_desc_STORE})/g`,
           `<span>${get_pstad_desc_STORE}</span>`
        );
   });
})
```

I'm open to a javascript or jquery solution.

Many thanks

Comment: `.replaceAll(get_pstad_desc_STORE, \`<span>${get_pstad_desc_STORE}</span>\`);`

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you for that, however because it's a loop it keeps finding get_pstad_desc_STORE every time it loops and adds another <span></span> to it unfortunately. Is there a way to do the above and once it replaces once with <span> it then breaks it from doing it any further?

Comment: but ... each loop is on a different div

Comment: @JaromandaX I upvoted your answer because it is correct in that if each div is different. However as Phil pointed out, my html looks like how he presented. Therefore it's looping through each div within the div and that was my problem. I appreciate you for your answer though ♥

Comment: I didn't post an answer, I posted a comment because I wasn't sure that was the answer

Comment: Appreciate ya :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your HTML looks something like this...

```html
<div id="pstad-descrptn-mirror">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        Take-away located in Brisbane, and comes with free chips
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- and so on -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with your current query is that it finds **all** the `<div>` elements that are children of the ID'd container.

You can use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) selector operator to only retrieve the immediate `<div>` children and operate on their content.

You can also use a regular expression to more easily extract your *store* string.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#pstad-descrptn-mirror > div").forEach((el) => {
  const store = el.textContent.match(/located in (.+?), and comes with/)?.[1];
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replaceAll(store, `<span>${store}</span>`);
});
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#pstad-descrptn-mirror > div").forEach((el) => {
  const store = el.textContent.match(/located in (.+?), and comes with/)?.[1];
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replaceAll(store, `<span>${store}</span>`);
});
```

```css
#pstad-descrptn-mirror span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="pstad-descrptn-mirror">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Take-away located in Brisbane, and comes with free chips.</p>
        <p>Located in Brisbane, QLD</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>No matches in this div, nothing will be replaced</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- and so on -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Phil, your amazing! This is exactly what I needed and helped me understand match and how to tackle divs within div's effecting my code. If I could buy you a coffee I would ♥